# Laravel File::delete not working

Tags: php, laravel

So I have a hidden input in my form where I set the name of old file

```
<input type="hidden" name="old_logo" value="{{ $company->logo }}">
```

And it is being set successfully:

`<input type="hidden" name="old_logo" value="GsdRHGtbm950k6tegfuyjjDlnC3ABg4uQKB2mHrE.jpeg"`>

Then it goes to my controller:

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    $company = Company::find($id);
    $company->name = $request->input('name');
    $company->address = $request->input('address');
    // $company->logo = $request->input('logo');
    if(null !== (($request->file('logo')))) {
        File::delete('logo/' . $request->input('old_logo'));
        $request->file('logo')->store('logo');
        $company->logo = $request->file('logo')->hashName();
    }
    $company->save();
    return redirect('admin/companies');
}
```

My file that I want to delete is stored in `storage/app/public/logo/`

Filesystems.php

```
    'disks' => [

        'local' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => storage_path('app/public'),
        ],

        'public' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => storage_path('app/public'),
            'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
            'visibility' => 'public',
        ],

        's3' => [
            'driver' => 's3',
            'key' => env('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'),
            'secret' => env('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'),
            'region' => env('AWS_DEFAULT_REGION'),
            'bucket' => env('AWS_BUCKET'),
        ],

    ],

];
```

It should be trying to delete from `storage/app/public/logo/` ? As I tested `$request->input('old_logo')` is passed successfully as well. What I'm doing wrong? Can it be rights problem? 
Ofcourse I wrote this: `use File;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass the full path to the file. So, if the file is in `public/logo` directory, do this:

```
File::delete(public_path('logo/' . $request->old_logo));
```

Comment: @Tomas you didn't tell where exactly the file is and I gave you an example. Where exactly is this file? And what does `dd($request->input('old_logo')))` show?

Comment: Why are you keeping full path in the form? it can be modified by a user. You shouldn't keep it in a form, but get it from DB or session. And you never should keep full path then you'll avoid so many problems like this one.

Comment: @Tomas if you're keeping just filename, use `public_path()` helper as I've shown. It will create a full path to the file. Also, check file permissions, make sure the directory and files can be deleted from the Laravel app.

Comment: in my case it should be like `File::delete(public_path('storage/logo/' . $request->input('old_logo')));` . Thanks for the help Alexey!